# SSO With Wordpress, Identity Server 4 and ASP .Net Core

Tags: wordpress, .net-core, single-sign-on, identityserver4

I currently have a need to build a single sign on solution between an externally developed WordPress site which is hosted by myself and 
and my own developed web application (built using ASP .Net core.  I also have my own developed Security Service based on Identity Server 4.

My requirements are as follows:

1. User will hit the home page of the wordpress site and be presented with a Login button.
2. When this button is pressed they will be passed over to my Security Service for authentication with a Username and Password
3. If these details are validated by the security service they will be then redirected back to the WordPress site where the homepage will now
   present a new button to edit their details.
4. When the user presses the "edit my details" button on the WordPress site they will now be redirected to my own developed web 
   application which will then retrieve them and display (with no additional user authentication required)

I am mainly wondering if there are any tutorials/examples out there that explain how to set this type of flow up with Identity Server 4 
as from looking up to now I am unable to locate any.

Any help in this would be most appreciated.

Stuart

Comment: You found IdentityServer but not the documentation http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/index.html and samples https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples?

Comment: Search for a wordpress OpenIdConnect client plugin (check the version) and configure IdentityServer as shown in one of the many examples. Read the documents to decide which flow suits best.